# Change layout of every two divs with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently wrapping every two divs in a parent row with php, which is working great.

However what I need to do is have it so that the `3rd & 4th, 7th & 8th` etc divs have a different layout. This is currently my code to wrap every two divs in a parent row.

```
<?php 
    if( have_rows('products') ) :
        $counter = 1;
        $i = 0;
        ?>
            <div class="o-table l-grid-half">
            <?php while( have_rows('products') ) : 
            the_row(); 
            if ($i > 0 && ($i % 2 == 0)) {
            // close row and open new row
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="o-table l-grid-half">
            <?php } ?>
                <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">
                    <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-table-cell o-table-vt l-grid-half__item o-full-sm-pd o-roman l-product__item o-bg-item-<?php echo($counter);?>">
                        <h3 class="hd-panel-sm"><?php the_sub_field('product_heading'); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_sub_field('product_summary'); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('product_link'); ?>" class="link-std clearfix"><i class="icon-right-open"></i><span>Find out more</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php   
             $i++;
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
     ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
    ?>
```

Everything I have tried to wrap it into the existing code has broken the script.

The end goal I would like the html to look like this (simplified version):

```
<div class="o-table im-the-parent-row">
    <div class="o-table-cell im-the-child-div">
        <img src="img-on-the-left.jpg"/>
        <p>text on the right</p>
    </div>
    <div class="o-table-cell im-the-child-div">
        <img src="img-on-the-left.jpg"/>
        <p>text on the right</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="o-table im-the-parent-row">
    <div class="o-table-cell im-the-child-div">
        <p>text on the left</p>
        <img src="img-on-the-right.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="o-table-cell im-the-child-div">
        <p>text on the left</p>
        <img src="img-on-the-right.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated code:

```
<?php 
    if( have_rows('products') ) :
        $counter = 1;
        $i = 0;
        ?>
            <div class="o-table l-grid-half">
            <?php while( have_rows('products') ) : 
            the_row(); 
            if ($i > 0 && ($i % 2 == 0)) {
            // close row and open new row
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="o-table l-grid-half">
            <?php } ?>

            <!--Row 3&4, 7&8  have the image on the left -->
             <?php if($i > 0 && (($i % 4 == 0) || (($i+1) % 4 == 0))) { ?>
                 <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">

                    <div class="o-table-cell o-table-vt l-grid-half__item o-full-sm-pd o-roman l-product__item o-bg-item-<?php echo($counter);?>">
                        <h3 class="hd-std-sm"><?php the_sub_field('product_heading'); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_sub_field('product_summary'); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('product_link'); ?>" class="link-std clearfix"><i class="icon-right-open"></i><span>Find out more</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php } else {?>
            <!--Row 1&2, 5&6  have the image on the right -->
                <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">
                    <div class="o-table-cell l-grid-half__item ">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image'); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-table-cell o-table-vt l-grid-half__item o-full-sm-pd o-roman l-product__item o-bg-item-<?php echo($counter);?>">
                        <h3 class="hd-std-sm"><?php the_sub_field('product_heading'); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_sub_field('product_summary'); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('product_link'); ?>" class="link-std clearfix"><i class="icon-right-open"></i><span>Find out more</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <?php } ?>

        <?php   
        $i++;
        $counter++;
        endwhile;?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: You should probably be using CSS for this - keyword `nth-child()` selector.

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you a "true" when $i is multiple of 4:

```
($i > 0 && ($i % 4 == 0))  # -> 4rd, 8th, etc
```

You can then shift $i to get the 3rd and 7th itens:

```
($i > 0 && ($i+1) % 4 == 0)  # -> 3rd, 7th, etc
```

EDIT - To get both cases at once:

```
if($i > 0 && (($i % 4 == 0) || (($i+1) % 4 == 0))) {
  /* do something... when $i = 3,4,7,8,11,12,... */ 
}
```

Comment: I need to get the 3rd & 4th item though. How would I do that?

Comment: Inside you while loop: if($i > 0 && (($i % 4 == 0) || (($i+1) % 4 == 0))) { /* do something... when $i = 3,4,7,8,11,12,... */ }

Comment: Thank you, but the above code is currently only getting the 3rd and 7th. I need to the 3rd and 4th. Then the 7th and 8th.

Comment: it's a simple logic matter... if you "or" the 2 conditions I gave you, they will execute in both cases... and get what you whant.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more in your answer? As I have implemented your code and its currently displaying the 3rd and 4th post differently.

Comment: whatever exception you whant to create in your HTML for rows 3,4,7,8,11,12,..., place-it inside the IF statement in my answer above

Comment: Really sorry, I dont seem to be able to get this to work. I have updated my code above with your PHP implemented.

Comment: Your code seems fine, a few advices: 1 - Don't relly on visual - check actual html source produced by your script (may be a CSS issue); 2 - put some debug information in html, like value of $i, value of expression "$i > 0 && (($i % 4 == 0) || (($i+1) % 4 == 0)))", etc... so that you can understand what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

1. Take one variable starts with 1
2. Increment with every loop... 1 2 3 4
3. After 4 move back to 1
4. When its 3 and 4 you can write your custom code.

(You can save as variable or in session as you wish)